# stat_summary add string as text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a boxplot which includes the number of samples per group. The code I am using so far looks something like this and works fine:

```r
set.seed(123)
plot_df <- data.frame(x_val=factor(sample(1:2, 90, replace = T)),
           y_val=runif(90),
           split=factor(sample(1:3, 90, replace = T)))


give.n <- function(x,ypos){
  return(c(y = ypos, label = length(x))) 
}

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x=x_val, y=y_val, fill=split))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.3)+
  geom_jitter(width=0.01,size=0.7)+
  facet_wrap(~split)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.args = list(ypos=-0.1),size=6)
```

I only want to modify one thing. Instead of simply adding the number of samples, I also want to add a small text, something like `n=`. However, if I modify `give.n` like this

```r
give.n <- function(x,ypos){
  return(c(y = ypos, label = paste0("n=",length(x))))
}
```

I get the following error:
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Can tell me, how I can add text to `stat_summary`?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have change it to a `dataframe` instead of `vector` in your `give.n` function. You can use the following code:

```
set.seed(123)
plot_df <- data.frame(x_val=factor(sample(1:2, 90, replace = T)),
                      y_val=runif(90),
                      split=factor(sample(1:3, 90, replace = T)))


give.n <- function(x,ypos){
  return(data.frame(y = ypos, label = paste0("n=",length(x))))
  }

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x=x_val, y=y_val, fill=split))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.3)+
  geom_jitter(width=0.01,size=0.7)+
  facet_wrap(~split)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.args = list(ypos=-0.1),size=6)
```

Output:

[image]